# In Carcassonne, how does the Bazaar play and count in different situations?

Tags: carcassonne

In Carcassonne, does the Bazaar in the farm play and count like a cloister in the farm? What about on the road and in a city?  We understand how to initiate the auctions but are not sure how to treat the Bazaar itself and for scoring purposes.  We assume it completes or ends a road.

Comment: Yes, welcome! I've edited the title to cover all the cases you asked about, and I've made small edits to the question. If you feel this changes what you were trying to say, feel free to roll back my changes, or to make other edits yourself!

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**,

Per the [Carcassonne Annotated Rules](http://carcassonnecentral.com/forum/index.php?topic=587.0), the Bazaar ends a road, although it is not directly stated.

> It seems clear that a bazaar ends a road in the same way as a crossing or bushes

The Bazaar itself is not a feature that a meeple can be put on.  It does not count as a cloister.  It doesn't change farm or city scoring.

Comment: What about the first question?  Does the bazaar play like a cloister in that a follower (meeple) can be placed on the bazaar?

Comment: @jon - did I answer your question?  I'm not certain I understand what you were looking for there.

Comment: OK, I appologize and now I see the answer above.  This is the first time using this site and I missed that answer, thanks!

Comment: @Jon - no worries, I did edit the answer to add the last paragraph.

Comment: We just received the tower and the count should be here today...we may be crazy, but we want to play the game with most or all the expansions...it took us 3 hours with the expansions I have todate.

Comment: @Jon - yeah, it's fun for a while, but for me, the base game is the most strategic and still encompasses a large majority of the fun while compressing the time required to play so we can get multiple games in

Comment: What we have been doing is limiting the time and ending the game before all the times have been played...it provides another level of randomness and unpredictability.  We still haven't been able to find a few of the expansions i.e. the plague, cathars, cult, etc.